# Connecting to a Postgres EC2 database

Tags: amazon-ec2, database, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a database hosted on AMAZON EC2:

```
ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.xxxx-1.amazonaws.com/companyName
```

I have been given the user and password for this.

```
What is the best way to connect to a database on this server?
```

I've tried this tool:

http://www.razorsql.com/register5.html

and also the postgres client to connect.

Thank you so much for your guidance/

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing ?

Comment: the problem is i don't understand how to connect to EC2? can i just use a regular db client ?

Comment: i know that they are running ubuntu

Comment: @golja please let me know how i can help you help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you host the postgresql as long you or the admin opened the appropriate ports. So make sure that the ubuntu firewall is open for postgresql and the security group on amazon has the same port open too. Check this article about [security group](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/)

Then you can use whichever client you prefer.

Comment: thanks so much for that article. i know that other people in other locations are able to connect, but i am not. i have forwarded that link to them and perhaps they just need to allow my IP in there

Comment: yep, looks like white listing my IP is what did the trick.